# link id use jquery pass the value into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="#" id="customer" class="link">Customer Registation</a>
```

I already get the linkID from link, How do you pass the linkID into form action `action=linkID`?

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#registationForm").fadeIn(300,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

<div id="registationForm" tabindex="-1">
<form id="registation-form" method="POST" action="registation/register.php?action=linkID">
</div>
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the `action` attribute ready to get linkID appended. Then using jquery you can select the `form` by id and then manipulate the `action`.

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkID = $(this).attr("id");

    //below three lines must be added.
    var $registrationForm = $('#registation-form');
    var actionLink = $registrationForm.attr('action');    
    $registrationForm.attr('action',actionLink + linkID );
    //end

    $("#registationForm").fadeIn(300,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

<div id="registationForm" tabindex="-1">
<form id="registation-form" method="POST" action="registation/register.php?action=">
</div>
```

if you are found of one liner code, you can try the below.

```
$('#registation-form').attr('action',$('#registation-form').attr('action')+ linkID )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var linkID,
    $formWrapper = $("#registationFormWrapper"),
    $form        = $("#registationForm");

$(".link").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  linkID = this.id;

  $formWrapper.fadeIn(300, function() {
    $form.find("input").focus();
  });

});

$form.on("submit", function() {
  this.action = "registation/register.php?action="+ linkID;
});
```

```css
#registationFormWrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="link" id="something" href="#">something</a>

<div id="registationFormWrapper">
  <form id="registationForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Click the link and than click Submit. Inspect the form in console to see the it's `action` attribute value